# How to use @yield to transfer it to variable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have yield from laravel how can I get the title of the page

```
<title>CDO | FDIS | @yield ('title')</title>
```

like this one

```
<?php $test = @yield ('title'); ?>
```

So I can use `$test` for another feature

Comment: You can't. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is a better way for your use case.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe take a step back and tell us what problem this code is attempting to solve.

Comment: I need to create a Dynamic access control list for my users

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Use app()->view:

You can use the `app` instance to retrieve the value of yield which is defined by a section.

**For example:**

```
// Assuming you have the following in your view: @section('title', 'Some Title')

$title = app()->view->getSections()['title']; // Some Title
```

The `app()->view->getSections()` returns an associative array of all the sections so, to get a specific section, specify the particular index from the array.

From the view, you can access the app using the global `$app` variable,
 i.e:

```
$app->view or $app['view'].
```

Answer (score 1):

First define section

```
@section('test')
   Hello World
@endsection
```

Then

```
<?php //@php
    $gotYieldValue =  e($__env->yieldContent('test'));
    echo $gotYieldValue; //This will print "Hello World"
 ?>  //@endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open the php tag: `<?php` you start writing actual PHP and therefore blade directories (such as `@yield` does not work).

If you need to include the result of `@yield` multiple times, you can just call it multiple times:

```
<title>@yield('title')</title>
...
<h1>@yield('title')</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

you must extend first the parent blade
then add

```
@section('title')
// content here
@endsection
```

Answer (score -1):

try below code

In views\layouts\app.blade.php

```
<title>@yield('title')</title>
```

In blade file

```
@section('title') Admin Management @stop
```